# Configure Visual Studio Code to have a default Build Task based on file extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to know if there is a way to define a default Build Task for VSCode depending on file extension.

When working in some folder of Python code, I define the following Build Task:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "python",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "args": ["${file}"]
}
```

Then if next time I go to another Python folder, I have to redefine it again.

Is it possible to configure VSCode in such a way that if it detects the current file as a Python script, then it will automatically define the above Build Task?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: One possible way to achieve this is to create related task and keybinding add  where condition to the keybinding `"when": "editorLangId == python"` [Mark answered Oct 7, 2020 at 17:01](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64248855/6345724). Software: VSCode 1.66.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I configure a task.json file for more then one language in vs code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62566196/can-i-configure-a-task-json-file-for-more-then-one-language-in-vs-code)

Comment: @Dan Thanks. Unfortunately I'm unable to answer your question. I haven't used this feature for a long time and I really don't remember what I asked for @@

Comment: As of today (vscode v1.71.2), there a shortcut in the menu `Terminal > Configure Default Build Task...`, and then you set your preferred default task to run (e.g. `npm run dev`), which you can run using the default keybinding `Ctrl+Cmd+B` on mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but it requires [writing an extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview) (unless somebody has already written one with a tasks provider for Python). Since 1.14.0, there's a new API which allows extensions to dynamically provide tasks. Check out the [Task Provider Example](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/task-provider-sample).

Alternatiely, the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension probably does the trick in this case as well. It doesn't use the Tasks system though.

Comment: for an example, see [How/Where is the VS Code task named "tsc: build - tsconfig.json" defined?](/q/76940885/11107541)

Answer (score 9):

**Update for latest vscode**

The following will create a default "build" script, so you can use the keyboard shortcut to build your project. (Below for a javascript project, but shows general outline for other languages/projects.)

(**1**) Assuming you have a script named "build.js" at the root of your project.

(**2**) Check that you have a ".vscode" hidden folder at the root of your project. If not, create it.

(**3**) Create a file named "tasks.json" in the ".vscode" folder at the root of project (workspace) with the following contents:

```
// .vscode/tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "mybuildscript", // use same name as in package.json
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
     ]
}
```

(**4**) In your package.json, add "scripts" as:

```
// package.json
{
    "name": "my",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "scripts": {
        "mybuildscript": "node ./build.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "myfs": "^1.0.22"
    }
}
```

I created a rudimentary vscode extension that does all this for you:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gieson.make-build-task

The extension isn't perfect (doesn't cover all the possible ways a project/workspace can be configured), but it's a good starting point.

Here's the repo:
https://github.com/bobtherobot/make-build-task