# Can I configure a task.json file for more then one language in vs code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to configure a `tasks.json` file in VS Code to run python and java code just pressing:

- `Ctrl + Shift + B`

Python and Java are configured but it needs two different `tasks.json` files.

But I can just keep one `tasks.json` file in the `.vscode` folder.

How can I merge two config file in a tasks.json file ?

For Python:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [{
    "label": "Compile and run",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "",
    "args": [
      "/usr/bin/time",
      "-v",
      "--output",
      "sys.txt",
      "timeout",
      "5",
      "python3",
      "${relativeFile}",
      "<",
      "input.txt",
      ">",
      "output.txt",
    ],
    "group": {
      "kind": "build",
      "isDefault": true
    },
    "problemMatcher": {
      "owner": "py",
      "fileLocation": [
        "relative",
        "${workspaceRoot}"
      ],
      "pattern": {
        "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
        "file": 1,
        "line": 2,
        "column": 3,
        "severity": 4,
        "message": 5
      }
    }
  }],


}
```

For Java :

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [{
    "label": "Compile and run",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "",
    "args": [
      "/usr/bin/time",
      "-v",
      "--output",
      "sys.txt",
      "timeout",
      "5",
      "java",
      "${relativeFile}",
      "<",
      "input.txt",
      ">",
      "output.txt",
    ],
    "group": {
      "kind": "build",
      "isDefault": true
    },
    "problemMatcher": {
      "owner": "java",
      "fileLocation": [
        "relative",
        "${workspaceRoot}"
      ],
      "pattern": {
        "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
        "file": 1,
        "line": 2,
        "column": 3,
        "severity": 4,
        "message": 5
      }
    }
  }],
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit June 2022

I managed to implement this and it’s now available in 1.68 https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_68#_tasks

Answer (score 9):

*If you have the java or python file open* (and the two tasks "merged" as @tHeSID suggested), you can just overload the keybindings ala:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+B",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "Compile and run Python",
    "when": "editorLangId == python"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+B",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "Compile and run Java",
    "when": "editorLangId == java"
  },
```

Answer (score 5):

Its simple, you just merge the `"tasks":[]` array and name your tasks uniquely. The tasks array can contain any number of Tasks Objects, some can be dependent on each other as well. [More info on VSCode Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

Here, when you use this and `CTRL + SHIFT + B` it will show you the option to select a task.

[image: Tasks option]

```js
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Compile and run Python",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "",
            "args": [
                "/usr/bin/time",
                "-v",
                "--output",
                "sys.txt",
                "timeout",
                "5",
                "python3",
                "${relativeFile}",
                "<",
                "input.txt",
                ">",
                "output.txt"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "py",
                "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Compile and run Java",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "",
            "args": [
                "/usr/bin/time",
                "-v",
                "--output",
                "sys.txt",
                "timeout",
                "5",
                "java",
                "${relativeFile}",
                "<",
                "input.txt",
                ">",
                "output.txt"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "java",
                "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Since there's no way to tell VSCode which task to run base on file extension ([See Issue here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88106)).

You can always create a keyboard shortcut for your build task and execute it without having to select it from the pop up. For example, for the below `tasks.json` you can create a shortcut by adding this to your `keybindings.json` file.

```
[{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+h",
  "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
  "args": "Compile and run Python" // this text should match exactly with task "label"
}]
```

Comment: Is there any way that it will automatically understand java or python file  executing ? 
I mean if i do as you have said it will prompt for selecting java or python !

Comment: Not as of now, [check this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88106) , you can create a shortcut for the task though, I've added how to do it in the ans

Comment: your task doc link is to the v0.1.0 version (VSC<=1.13), we now use task v2.0.0 files

Answer (score 1):

As JaseW pointed out, support for glob patterns for default tasks was added in 1.68 (credz to you, JaseW), however the glob pattern described in the linked update notes (`**.ext`) only works for files that are in the root of the workspace. To match all files with a given extension, you should use `**/*.ext`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo txt",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo TextFile",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": "**/*.txt" // This is a glob pattern which will only match when the active file has a .txt extension.
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "echo js",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo JavascriptFile",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": "**/*.js" // This is a glob pattern which will only match when the active file has a .js extension.
            },
        }
    ]
}
```